# How to make two different cursors for Tooltip while hover on a stacked bar chart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recharts

So in my case when I hover on a bar, I need to have two different cursors, one is the line in front of the bar, second one is the grey background which is behind the bar, I will attach 2 pictures of these cursors as I want them, but I haven't found a solution how to combine both of these. So You can look on an [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/stacked-bar-chart-forked-mujysf?file=/src/App.tsx) here, and just comment one "Tooltip" and uncomment other and vise versa to understand what behaviour I expect, but again I want to combine these two into one. One of my ideas was to render a Tooltip after everything else, but in this case the grey background will be in front of the Bar and will cover it, so i thought to render only part of this grey background, but in this case on Bar hover i get the height of only a small part with one color, not an all Bar, so I'm not being able to get the full Bar height

[This is a line cursor in front of the Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igAdP.png)
[This is a background cursor behind the Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utp7c.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This is looks pretty clear, I need two different cursors, as I show on pictures, I can make it work only one way at a time, but I want to have both cursors at the same time, the line in front of the bar and the background Grey color